# A stack of divs above other divs contains divs inside of them?

Tags: html, css, stack, row

One of my website pages is current messed up. I'm having a hard time getting the biographies in for my crew of lovable misfits. Here is the webpage:

http://www.sampsonvision.com/about/

The code for this webpage can be found in the about folder in the website files inside this zip folder here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZPyNRv7C3hemJERHZYVWFtSDg/edit?usp=sharing

May you please help me fix the divs so that the pictures are all in a nice little column and the text is directly next to the image, telling the user all about that particular crew member? I don't want the elements going all over the place like you see in the sampsonvision.com page above.

Comment: You have to write all your code from scratch, from HTML to CSS, can't possibly savage it. Anyways, start by NOT using the absolute position unless you REALLY need it (which, in your case, seems to be not needed at all)

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty div to the end of each section with the class "clear".

```
<div class="jordansbio">
    <div class="jordanpic">
        <img src="images/jordanwhite.jpg" width="150" height="170">
    </div>
    <div class="jordaninfo">
        <span class="jwhit">
            <h2 align="center">Jordan White</h2>
            <p>Testing, Testing, 1, 2, 3</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Then add the following CSS style

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

What you're facing is a very common issue encountered with using floats to position content. Basically with all of your elements floated, none of them are considered to have height and so the container itself has a height of 0.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html